# How do I get the value from a specific Key with Key Value Pair and VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, key-value

```
Public _SecurityLevel As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer))

Public Sub New()
    _SecurityLevel.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(1, 0))
    _SecurityLevel.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(2, 1))
    _SecurityLevel.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(3, 2))
    _SecurityLevel.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(4, 3))
    _SecurityLevel.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(5, 4))
    _SecurityLevel.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(6, 5))
End Sub
```

I want to get the value (3) when I specify the Key (4).

I don't want to iterate through the entire KVP until I find it.

Is this possible? If not what should I be using?

Comment: Yes, with LINQ.

Comment: If you are using Key/Value pairs, why not just use a Dictionary to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Dictionary seems more appropriate for your application.

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Public _SecurityLevel As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

    Public Sub New()
        _SecurityLevel.Add(1, 0)
        _SecurityLevel.Add(2, 1)
        _SecurityLevel.Add(3, 2)
        _SecurityLevel.Add(4, 3)
        _SecurityLevel.Add(5, 4)
        _SecurityLevel.Add(6, 5)
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim sc As New SomeClass
    Dim v = sc._SecurityLevel(4)
    Debug.Print(v.ToString)
    'Prints 3
End Sub
```

It would be unusual to have a public field in a class.

Answer (score 3):

You can get it by using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq):

```
Dim theValue As Integer = _SecurityLevel.Find(Function(kvp) kvp.Key = 4).Value
```

But I would recommend to use a [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) instead, if no duplicate keys should occur.

```
Dim _SecurityLevel As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)           
_SecurityLevel.Add(1, 0)
_SecurityLevel.Add(2, 1)
_SecurityLevel.Add(3, 2)
_SecurityLevel.Add(4, 3)
_SecurityLevel.Add(5, 4)
_SecurityLevel.Add(6, 5)

Dim result As Integer
_SecurityLevel.TryGetValue(4, result)
```

**Edit**

As stated in the comments, `FindIndex` would be the better joice here, as `Find` will return a default `KeyValuePair` with key/value `(0,0)` if no entry is found in the list.
Something like the following would be more reliable:

```
Dim index As Integer = _SecurityLevel.FindIndex(Function(kvp) kvp.Key = 4)
If index > -1 Then
    MsgBox(_SecurityLevel(index).Value)
Else
    'Not found
End If
```

Comment: Note that `_SecurityLevel.Find(Function(kvp) kvp.Key = 8).Value` will return `0`, which is a possible valid value and it may be misleading (the Key doesn't exist but a valid value is returned). This because `Find()` returns `Default<T>` if not matches are found and `KeyValuePair` defaults to `(0, 0)`

Comment: A cheap alternative if to use `FindIndex()`. E.g., `dim theIndex = _securityLevel.FindIndex(Function(kvp) kvp.Key = 8)` and return the KVP at that index if `theIndex` is `> -1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim valueFromKey As Integer = (From currentValue In _SecurityLevel.AsEnumerable
                               Where currentValue.Key = 4
                               Select currentValue.Value).FirstOrDefault
```